# Publish Visual Studio não se conecta a computador remoto (Web Deploy)

Tags: visual-studio, asp, deploy

Ao tentar publicar minha aplicação via Visual Studio (`Publish...`), tenho como retorno uma mensagem de erro informando que não foi possível se conectar ao computador remoto. O `Web Deploy` do servidor está instalado e o serviço está rodando normalmente, e não há regras de `Firewall` que bloqueiem o serviço. Os parâmetros e conexão como: ip, nome do site e dados de login estão corretos... Estou usando `Windows Server 2012 R2` e `IIS V 6.2` , `Web Deploy 3.5`

Imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem do Serviço:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço nada disso aí (web deploy etc), mas essa mensagem "destination not reachable" é típico problema de rede...rode `ping`, `tracert`, tente acessar o Web Deploy via telnet, faça um trace de rede com `tcpdump`, enfim procedimentos usuais para testar conectividade.

Apesar do que você disse sobre os firewalls, ainda existe a possibilidade de que seja algum firewall barrando a conexão, talvez algum firewall intermediário.

Pode ser também problema de roteamento, em algum ponto da rede entre seu computador e o servidor. Se você conseguir descobrir o caminho da rede do seu computador até o destino, você pode tentar um telnet em cada um desses pontos. Se conseguir acessar um nó intermediário provavelmente vai ter um erro de "conexão recusada", se não conseguir vai ter um erro de "destination unreachable" (ou erro parecido).